# How could click reaction take place at low concentration?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, concentration

I have DBCO-functionalized resin, and the DBCO group is validated with FAM-azide.

But I cannot use this resin to react with FAM-Azide-labled primer, which has very low concentration (20 μM, it is already very concentrate at DNA-scale).

I think that might be caused by concentration, because the reaction between DBCO-resin and FAM-azide is also not significant at such low concentration.

I have already tried long reaction time and higher temperature.
How could I get this work?

Comment: A couple of thoughts: (1) Can you get your FAM-azide conjugate to react with anything? I realize this might be a difficult question to answer, but seeing as you've confirmed the reactivity of the DMCO-resin, it's the next logical question. (2) Use more resin.

Comment: @jerepierre Hi, thank you for your reply. I have negative control that shows FAM-azide cannot react with COOH-functionalized beads. (2) Do you mean I need more resin to react with primer? Base on the concentration, the DBCO on the resin already exceeds a lot.

Comment: Have you tried reacting the FAM-azide with some other alkyne, whether on solid support or not? You need some indication that the azide is reactive at all. You might also consider a Staudinger type conjugation to solid support. I asse that there's a resin available for that.